# Default Formatting Templates don't add "required" to input tag

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I've just started using FreeForm and so far it's fantastic after moving away from another solution.

One thing I'm struggling with is how the "required" option works for fields. I would have expected it to add a required attribute to the input field, but all it does is add a required class to the label of that input.

I know I can add the required attribute myself and that's what I'm doing now but wanted to check I'm not doing something wrong? The formatting template I'm using is Bootstrap 4 and I can see it only uses required in relation to labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it doesn't add them. You can get that added automatically by adding `useRequiredAttribute: true` to your form embed tag: https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/template-objects/field.html#properties

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.